# Crystal Report doesn't Display ISNULL Alternative Within a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a stored procedure which selects various information about suppliers.

One of these details is a name, however when the 'name' field IS NULL in one table, I want to bring in the data from another.

Basically it's a fail-safe in case it's a new supplier who hasn't been added to the first table yet.

I'm currently doing something like this within my SELECT statement;

```
ISNULL(A.[SupplierName], (B.SupplierForname + ' ' + B.SupplierSurname)) AS SupplierName,
```

Where have I gone wrong?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comments, and yes, the problem is not with Crystal Reports, SSMS doesn't produce the records either.

If I just run this;

```
(B.SupplierForname + ' ' + B.SupplierSurname) AS SupplierName,
```

It works fine, therefore, why shouldn't it work within the ISNULL() statement?

Comment: have you tried running the procedure in ssms - not with crystal reports - to see if it is returning the data you think it is?

Comment: Can you post the whole query?  What results are you getting/expecting?  Do you have an outer join to table A?

Comment: I don't see how Crystal would know SupplierName in your proc is based on an isnull function.

Comment: @ Fiona T - The query is very long and the rest of it executes fine, the tables are INNER joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure both B.SupplierForname and  B.SupplierSurname are not null?
Is B.SupplierForname spelt correctly (SupplierForename?)

Comment: Yes, the spelling is 'correct'. Also the details are guaranteed to be within 'Table B', no nulls.